# Dynamic Provider in Nest JS

Tags: design-patterns, dynamic, nestjs, repository, provider

Today I have a payment service based on Nest JS.

I have 3 payment methods: PIX (brazilian payment), Boleto (brazilian payment) and credit card.

These payment methods are linked to a payment gateway (PagSeguro (Brazilian), PayPal etc.)

So I created a service like: createPixCharge, createBoletoCharge, createCreditCardCharge. These services communicate with the payment gateway API.

To make the code clean and scalable, I used the repository pattern. So, there is an abstract repository with methods like: createPixCharge (which returns a code that the customer will pay in his Brazilian bank - this code is universal)

I did this because today I use API 1, tomorrow I can switch to another platform.

Therefore, what could I do to, according to the chosen payment method, inject the desired repository dependency?

For example:

if customer chooses payment method X, it will inject API dependency 1. If client chooses payment method Y, it will inject API dependency 2

As I said, I created a service like createPixCharge, createBoletoCharge and createCreditCardCharge, which when invoked, depending on the payment method, will call the repository that integrates with the API.

But I don't know how to relate it all.

Comment: Normally, you hide the selection algorithm behind a factory. The factory depends on all possible payment methods and exposes a single `getPaymentMethod(type: PaymentMethodEnum): IPaymentMethod` method.

Comment: If your selection algorithm is trivial and basically maps 1:1 to `PaymentMethodEnum`, then you may want to take it further and declare that as metadata, e.g. `@PaymentMethod(PaymentMethodEnum.Pix) export class PixPaymentMethod implements IPaymentMethod {...}`. The factory then depends on an `IPaymentMethod[]` and returns `methods.find(x => getPaymentMethodMeta(x) === type)`.